# Need some help with this program

Tags: xetex

How do i run this program ; because in texmaker it gives error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}
\begin{document}
\setRTL
\urdufont
j j  k i l a d 
\end{document}
```

I get the error message:

> ! fatal font spec error The font spec package either requires xetex 
>   or LuaTeX to function

while running the given MWE with ???.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Good that you have provided a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). A problem description would be nice.

Comment: There is a typo in the code: `\usepakage{fontspec}` should be corrected to `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Comment: well while i run this program in texmaker with correct \usepackage then it gives the error "! fatal font spec error The font spec package either requires xetex or r LuaTeX to function"

and now i tried to run it in winedt 6 and its taking forever 
so tell me how to run it ; i dont know a bit about xetex or how to use winedt 6 
till now i have only used texmaker and all programs worked correctly

Comment: And did you run it with LuaLaTeX or XeTeX? Please have a look at the TeXMaker documentation (sorry, don't know that software so well) on how to do that. For sure, you can choose that next to your "compile" or "built" button. Default will be LaTeX or PDFLaTeX I guess.

Comment: #1: Install the font;
http://jameel-noori-nastaleeq-urdu-fonts.software.informer.com/1.0/

#2: add \usepackage{bidi}

#3: should look like:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setRTL
\newfontfamily\urdufont [Script=Arabic,Scale=1.4]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}
\begin{document}
\urdufont
j j  k i l a d 
\end{document}

#4: Compile this with XeLaTeX

Works for me.